# User Profile Synchronization Service status sits in "Starting" status for sometime and finally status changed to "Stopped"

Tags: user-profile-service, mysites

We are migrating User Profile Synchronization service from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 using content database attach upgrade method.

We have a fully configured and working state SharePoint 2010 environment. We have created a new SharePoint 2013 farm, during the installation we did not configure "User Profile Service Application" and "Managed Metadata Service Application" services using the standard configurations wizard in Central Administration as per the recommendations in Microsoft article.

We are able to upgrade databases using the PowerShell commands as per the standard Microsoft articles. We are seeing the upgraded user profiles in SharePoint 2013 as well. Problem, is we are not able to start the "User Profile Synchronization Service". When we click on "Start" button for this service from "Central Administration, Application Management, Manage services on the server", it is showing "starting" status for sometime and then finally status sets to "Stopped".

Did anyone face similar issue and what is the resolution?

Thanks

Reference Link:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj839719.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the following:

- You are using the Farm Account to start UPSs.
- The Farm account is added to local administrator group during starting UPS service.
- Adding the service account running User Profile Sync Service to local administrator group on the server running Distributed Cache.
- AppFabricCachingService in services is running via Farm account.

**Note:**

- After adding the farm account to local administrator group, you must restart the SharePoint 2013 Timer service.
- Adding farm account to local administrator group is required only to start the User Profile Synchronization service. After the User Profile Synchronization service is started, you can remove the farm account from the Administrators group. for more details check.
- if you are using SQL server 2014 RTM with SharePoint 2013, in this case, update SQL Server 2014 RTM to SQL Server 2014 SP2, Patch your farm with the June 2014 CU or higher one.

For more details check [User Profile Synchronization Service Starting then Stopped in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/05/user-profile-synchronization-service-starting-and-stoped/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to unprovision the server using the following command.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$ServiceName = "User Profile Synchronization Service"
$ServerName = "SERVERNAME" 
$Serviceinstance = Get-SPServiceInstance | where-object {$_.TypeName -eq $serviceName -and $_.Server.Address -eq $ServerName}
$Serviceinstance.Unprovision()
```

Then run the provision again

```
$Serviceinstance.provision()
```

If this still not working, i would suggest you to delete and create the user profile service then installed June CU
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ianragusa/2014/06/23/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-start-the-user-profile-synchronization-service/